# Pass variable two to controller

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Here is my controller code:

```
public function search_records() {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
    $data = array (
    'employeeName' => $this->input->post('employeeName'),
    'userID' => $this->input->post('userID'),
    'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
    'timeSelect' => $this->input->post('timeSelect'),
    'error_message' => 'Sorry there is no record !'
    );

    if($data['employeeName'] !== '' OR $data['userID'] !== '') 
    {
        if(isset($data['date']))
        {
            if($data['timeSelect'] == 1)
            {
                $data['time1'] = '00:00:00';
                $data['time2'] = '23:59:00';
                $result_from_db= $this->mrecord->search_by_id_or_name_with_date($data);
                if($result_from_db == false)
                {
                    $data['show_search_error_message'] = 'Sorry, there is no record !';
                    $this->load->view('vhome', $data);
                }else {
                    $data['result_display'] = $result_from_db->result();
                    $data['row_count'] = count($result_from_db->result());
                    $this->session->set_userdata("excel_data", $result_from_db->result());
                    $this->pagi($data);
                }

            }else {
                $data['time1'] = '12:30:00';
                $data['time2'] = '15:30:00';
                $result_from_db = $this->mrecord->search_by_id_or_name_with_date($data);
                if($result_from_db == false)
                {
                    $data['show_search_error_message'] = 'Sorry, there is no record !';
                    $this->load->view('vhome', $data);
                }else {
                    $data['result_display'] = $result_from_db->result();
                    $data['row_count'] = count($result_from_db->result());
                    $this->session->set_userdata("excel_data", $result_from_db->result());
                    $this->pagi($data);
                }   
            }
        }else {
            $data['error_message'] = 'Something is wrong ! Please check your date .';
            $this->load->view('vhome', $data);
        }
    }else if(isset($data['date']))
    {
        if($data['timeSelect'] == 1)
        {
            $data['time1'] = '07:00:00';
            $data['time2'] = '19:00:00';
            $result_from_db = $this->mrecord->search_by_date($data);
            if($result_from_db == false)
            {
                $data['error_message'] = 'Sorry, there is no record !';
                $this->load->view('vhome', $data);
            }else {
                $data['result_display'] = $result_from_db->result();
                $data['row_count'] = count($result_from_db->result());
                $this->session->set_userdata("excel_data", $result_from_db->result());
                $this->pagi($data);
            }
        }else {
            $data['time1'] = '12:30:00';
            $data['time2'] = '15:30:00';
            $result_from_db = $this->mrecord->search_by_date($data);
            if($result_from_db == false)
            {
                $data['error_message'] = 'Sorry, there is no record !';
                $this->load->view('vhome', $data);
            }else {
                $data['result_display'] = $result_from_db->result();
                $data['row_count'] = count($result_from_db->result());
                $this->session->set_userdata("excel_data", $result_from_db->result());
                $this->pagi($data);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $data['error_message'] = 'Oops ... you can not search without input !';
        $this->load->view('vhome', $data);
    }
 }else {
     redirect ('welcome', 'refresh');
 }
```

Here is my model:

```
public function search_by_id_or_name_with_date($data) {
    if($data['userID'] == '')
    {
    $condition = "employeeName =" . "'" . $data['employeeName'] . "'";
    }else {
        $condition = "employeeID =" . "'" . $data['userID'] . "'";
    }
    $condition2 = "date =" . "'" . $data['date'] . "'";
    $condition1 = "time BETWEEN " . "'" . $data['time1'] . "'" . "AND" . "'" . $data['time2'] . "'";
    $this->db->select('employeeID, employeeName, departmentName, date, time, tb_inout.doorStatus');
    $this->db->from('tb_access_logs');
    $this->db->join('tb_inout', 'tb_access_logs.doorID = tb_inout.doorID');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->where($condition1);
    $this->db->where($condition2);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function search_by_date($data) {
    $condition = "date =" . "'" . $data['date'] . "'";
    $condition1 = "time BETWEEN " . "'" . $data['time1'] . "'" . "AND" . "'" . $data['time2'] . "'";
    $this->db->select('employeeID, employeeName, departmentName, date, time, tb_inout.doorStatus');
    $this->db->from('tb_access_logs');
    $this->db->join('tb_inout', 'tb_access_logs.doorID = tb_inout.doorID');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->where($condition1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <?php
        $this->load->helper('array');
                if (isset($result_display)) {

                        echo "<div class=container>";
                        echo "<h2>Result</h2>";
                        echo "<p>All result was generated from BioStar Database</p>";
                        echo "<table class='table table-hover' data-toggle='table'
                                                                data-show-export='true'
                                                                data-pagination='true'
                                                                data-click-to-select='true'
                                                                data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                                                                data-url='../json/data1.json'>";
                        echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Employee ID</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Department Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>State</th></tr>";
                        echo "</thead>";
                        echo "<tbody>";
                        foreach ($result_display as $value) {
                            echo '<tr>' . '<td>' . $value->employeeID . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value->employeeName . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value->departmentName . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value->date . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value->time  . '</td>' . '<td>' . $value->doorStatus . '</td>' . '</tr>';
                        }
                        echo "</tbody>";
                        echo "</table>";
                }else {
                    echo '<div class="row">';
                    echo '<center>' . $error_message . '</center>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    $this->output->set_header('refresh:3; url='. base_url("crecord"));
                }
 ?>
```

Here is my Excel export controller:

```
class Excel extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        redirect('crecord', 'refresh');
    }else {
        redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
    }
}

public function report()
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->model('mrecord');
    $result_data = $this->session->userdata("excel_data");
    $headers = ''; // just creating the var for field headers to append to below
    $data = ''; // just creating the var for field data to append to below

    $fields = array('Employee ID', 'Employee Name', 'Department Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'State');
    if ($result_data == 0) {
        echo '<p>The table appears to have no data.</p>';
    } else {
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
           $headers .= $field . "\t";
        }

        foreach ($result_data as $row) {
            $line = '';
            foreach($row as $value) {                                            
                if (( ! isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
                    $value = "\t";
                } else {
                    $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
                    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                }
                $line .= $value;
            }
            $data .= trim($line)."\n";
        }

        $data = str_replace("\r","",$data);

        force_download("Report.xls", $headers . "\n" . $data);
}
```

}
}

When I try to export by choosing first option to Excel, it is ok.
But when I tried to export second option (date only) it does not work.